# RuntimeException when converting Dataset<Row> to JavaRDD<Row> and then Dataframe

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd

I am trying to add an index column to the Dataset using below code that converts it to a JavaPairRDD.

```
// ds is a Dataset<Row>
JavaPairRDD<Row, Long> indexedRDD = ds.toJavaRDD()
    .zipWithIndex();

// Now I am converting JavaPairRDD to JavaRDD as below.
JavaRDD<Row> rowRDD = indexedRDD
    .map(tuple -> RowFactory.create(tuple._1(),tuple._2().intValue()));

// I am converting the RDD back to dataframe and it doesnt work.
Dataset<Row> authDf = session
    .createDataFrame(rowRDD, ds.schema().add("ID", DataTypes.IntegerType));

// Below is the ds schema(Before adding the ID column).
ds.schema()

root
 |-- user: short (nullable = true)
 |-- score: long (nullable = true)
 |-- programType: string (nullable = true)
 |-- source: string (nullable = true)
 |-- item: string (nullable = true)
 |-- playType: string (nullable = true)
 |-- userf: integer (nullable = true)
```

The above code throws the following error message:

```
**Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 21.0 failed 4 
times, most  recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 21.0 (TID 658, 
sl73caehdn0406.visa.com, executor 1):

java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Error while encoding: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema is not 
a valid external type for schema of smallint**
```

Comment: It is not clear which step is throwing the exception exactly due to spark's nature of being lazy and only acting when there is an action. You might as a simple debugging step print your structure after each step with `.show()` which will usually just print the first 20 rows. That will force spark to calculate each step sequentially any you will encounter the error when it occurs instead of after your workflow.

Answer (score 0):

The tuple you have created in your second statement consists of two columns: one is the object (that consists of all the colmns from the initial data set), and the second is integer.
Second tuple column goes into second result column, which is of type long.
First tuple column goes into first result column, which is of type short - being an object, i.e. GenericRowWithSchema, this leads to an error.

You should do your RowFactory.create() with 7 parameters, one for each result column.